# acer v3-572g sceen blank on login after nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, acer

Hi my gf wants ubuntu (14.04) on her acer v3-572g. She needs the Nvidia 840m for games but still wants to use the Intel igpu for power saving.

I get the nvidia 340 drivers installed for the 840m and as long as I dont update from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa afterwards it logs in just fine. However if I run the updates or have bumblebee installed the computer boots with the splash showing, and then I hear sound of the login screen but its blank and theres no display unless I drop to console. From console I can remove nvidia drivers and get it working again. Not updating from the ppa the computer works okay with the gpu aside from the screen freezes.

some of the things Ive tried

([Ubuntu 14.04 and Nvidia GeForce (840M) compatability on 64-bit laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518985/ubuntu-14-04-and-nvidia-geforce-840m-compatability-on-64-bit-laptop))

([Nvidia 840M driver installation Acer E5-571](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580075/nvidia-840m-driver-installation-acer-e5-571))

Answer (score 0):

Same here, with a HP-Envy15, Nvidia 840M as well, Ubuntu 14.10.

Updating packages including `xorg-edgers` PPA gives a black screen on boot,
then the only way I found was to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, login, completely uninstall Nvidia packages, reinstall ubuntu-desktop, reinstall ccsm, launch ccsm, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and re-enabling Ubuntu-desktop-plugin from CompizManager.

Comment: I tried Marko's answer from the link below. I didn't update until I had intel swapped from the Nvidia settings which required a reboot to get that option. Plus I haven't made the changes he mentions to the xorg.conf. Have not tried switching to nvidia yet. http://askubuntu.com/questions/582857/nvidia-840m-boots-to-blank-screen-ubuntu-14-04/583132#583132

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance afterwards about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.